# Использование переменной из массива (Сообщение в Telegram)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть массив сообщения, пример(Уже декодирован):

```html
array (
  'update_id' => 222742217,
  'message' => 
  array (
    'message_id' => 127527,
    'from' => 
    array (
      'id' => 111111111,
      'is_bot' => false,
      'first_name' => 'First',
      'last_name' => 'Last',
      'username' => 'user1',
      'language_code' => 'ru-RU',
    ),
    'chat' => 
    array (
      'id' => -1001082662471,
      'title' => 'Name',
      'username' => 'usnameg',
      'type' => 'supergroup',
    ),
    'date' => 1530710879,
    'reply_to_message' => 
    array (
      'message_id' => 127519,
      'from' => 
      array (
        'id' => 22222222,
        'is_bot' => false,
        'first_name' => 'Name',
        'username' => 'usname2',
        'language_code' => 'ru-RU',
      ),
      'chat' => 
      array (
         'id' => -1001082662471,
         'title' => 'Name',
         'username' => 'usnameg',
         'type' => 'supergroup',
      ),
      'date' => 1530710183,
      'text' => 'Text',
    ),
    'text' => 'Text',
    'entities' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'offset' => 0,
        'length' => 5,
        'type' => 'bot_command',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

При записи **$array['message']['reply_to_message']['from']['id']**, я могу использовать данную переменную в условиях If.
Но при попытке вывести ее с помощью того же echo, получаю пустую переменную.

Вопрос, как я могу использовать данную часть массива как самостоятельную переменную.

Comment: вы уже вывели `print_r($array)` теперь последовательно добавьте `print_r($array['message'])` и так далее уровни вложенности. Мб найдете опечатку.  Нет разницы, используете вы это в `if` или просто при выводе.

Comment: @teran Дело в том что, в if это отлично работает. А вот если вывести данную переменную, тогда я получаю пустое значение.

Comment: Вообщем, вопрос решен. Решил написать в комментариях его, ибо он очень уж странный.
Например, есть две переменный:
 $user_id_for_mute = $date['id'];
 $text_per_chat = $data['id'];
Первая не выводит значения, вторая работает исправно. Между ними нет никакой разницы.

Comment: Разница есть. `date` и `data` - разные массивы. Настройте вывод ошибок `E_ALL`, чтобы замечать подобные недоразумения